# How do I enter the token when you download a json on python?

Tags: python-2.7

I need to download a JSON, and found one of the NOAA, but this one has a token to access the information. How do I enter the token in my program or which variables could be used to gain access to that information.
my English is not very good, I am a student and I have recently started to use python, i hope i can help.

Comment: It varies depending on the API, but a quick Google of NOAA's API says that they want you to pass your token in the header. https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to guess a bit about what you mean, but this may help.

See the doc.python-request.org

To install "requests" (works under linux, perhaps elsewhere):

```
pip install requests
```

then code like this:

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.noaa.gov/id'
head = {'Authorization': 'access_token hex_string'}
res=requests.get(url, headers=head)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is of great help to me!